# PHPunit doesn't work properly during a Jenkins build of CakePHP app

Tags: cakephp, jenkins, phpunit

I faced a weird behavior of PHPunit 3.7.3 during CakePHP 2.x tests.

We migrated Jenkins from an old well-working server to a new one. Our build is made by Phing, source code is stored on Github.

Code from build.xml which runs the tests:

```
<exec dir="." command=" ${sourcedir}/app/Console/cake test app AllQaTests --stderr --log-junit '${builddir}/logs/unitreport.xml'  --coverage-clover '${builddir}/logs/coverage/coverage.xml' --coverage-html '${builddir}/logs/coverage'" />
```

In the new configuration a suite of 10 PHPUnit tests take 10 minutes to finish (100 times more than while using old configuration) and each of the tests fails after 60 seconds (looks like a time-out termination). Example of error from unitreport.xml:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Argument #2 of 
PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertObjectHasAttribute() must be a object
```

Other type of error is

```
..."PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException">
TerminalTest::testInsertCustomTerminal  Failed asserting that null is true.
```

It seems that PHPUnit has a connectivity issue with a test database of Cake, however it's configured identically to the old configuration.

Any ideas how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fixed. Tests were configured for environment with a dynamic IP and were trying to reach the web service internally with no success, but in the new server we have static IP and addressing must be changed to global.